# How to add horizontal lines to a ggplot2 grouped barplot

Tags: ggplot2, barplot

I have created a grouped barplot with ggplot2 consisting of 4 groups (x-axis) with each 4 subgroups (bars).

I now want to add a horizontal line (representing a threshold) similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882335/add-group-mean-line-to-barplot-with-ggplot2). However, I need 4 different lines for each bar (subgroup) in the plot.

I have already created the horizontal lines using 
`Geom_errorbar` but these lines are all positioned  above the respective x-axis section of the group and not in the middle of each bar (subgroup).

how can I change the positions for each of the 4 lines. Or do I have to use a different approach to create lines in a barplot?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supplying an MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example) helps the community to understand your question better as well as providing a more accurate response. However, I will do my best. I think you want to use geom_segment(), like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

y = c(10,15,20)

x = c("group1", "group2", "group3")

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = x, y = y), stat = "identity") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.5, xend = 1.5, y = 11, yend = 11)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5, xend = 2.5, y = 16, yend = 16)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.5, xend = 3.5, y = 21, yend = 21))
```

[image: Grouped barplot with user defined line segments]

See the tidyverse help page for more information: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.
Thank you very much!